# Android studio 2.3.3 cannot write to external storage of emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am an absolute beginner with Android. My app writes to external storage. When I execute my program on a real device, it executes perfectly. So no problem with the code.(manifest file also ok).
However, when I test with the emulator, my program cannot write to the external storage of the emulator. I read that I have to give permission to my app in order to write to the external storage of the emulator.
I have looked in great detail but I do not find how to do this on the emulator of Android Studio 2.3.3. 
Thank you for helping this absolute beginner.

Comment: If the app is working on a real device, the permission will be correctly set. Seems to be a problem of the virtual device you are using in the emulator. Does it have an emulated external storage?

Answer (score 1):

I have found the cause of the problem: when running the app in the AVD, I have to give PERMISSIONS to the app: in my case the permission STORAGE. When I do this my app is able to write to the external storage of the AVD, just like it is able to write to the external storage of my real device.
However my real device prompts me to give the permissions, while the AVD does not.
Thank you for helping me with this newbie problem.

Comment: Please add the code that solved the problem, people may want to see that here. After that, mark your own answer as correct, if possible ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Find out what kind of AVD (virtual device used by the emulator) you are using in Android Studio:
select Tools > Android > AVD Manager.
 Maybe it is a default one that does not have an emulated external storage. There is an AVD Manager available in Android Studio. See [Create and Manage Virtual Devices | Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds.html) section AVD Properties. There is a little description about emulating external SD cards:[image: partial screenshot of AVD Properties]

Comment: I am using AVD Pixel XL API 25. This virtual device has 1536 MB RAM, 800 MB internal storage and 300 MB SD-card Studio Managed. I think this should be OK, but when my app executes a "files.mkdirs()" command, mkdirs gives a return code false. I also test if the external storage is writeable: it is writeable.

Comment: That's somehow weird… Where on your computer drives do the avd and its storage get emulated? It's rather unlikely, but maybe android studio may write to the folder (and create the avd) and the app may not and so `files.mkdirs()` fails. Really unlikely, thinking about that twice. What causes `files.mkdirs()` to return `false`? Can you get an `Exception`?

Comment: public File getAlbumStorageDir(String albumName)
    {
        
    // Get the directory for the user's public pictures directory.
     File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), albumName);
        
        if (!file.mkdirs())
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "Directory not created");
        }
       return file;

    }

Comment: Sorry about the lousy layout of this code snippet. What I tested was if the directory PICTURES exists: it does, but the mkdirs returns false. I also surrounded the file.mkdirs() command with a try catch clause but the code within the catch-part is skipped. This would mean that mkdirs does not return an exception.

Comment: It throws a `SecurityException`, but obviously not necessarily when returning false. [see API](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#mkdirs())

Comment: I do not know what makes mkdirs() fail. I can think about a permission problem or that mkdirs() tries to create an already existing file. But this is not the case.

Comment: Have you tried using `mkdir()` and choose an existing folder? Does that fail, too?

Comment: Very good proposal, but I do not know how in the emulator. I do not know how to access the file explorer.

Comment: I am sorry I have to leave here. I will try to do some more testing on the real device in order to be more sure about the cause of the problem: is it in my code or is there something in the emulator. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Just take the root directory of the emulated card and try to create a file or directory